# React-grid-layout - ширина дочерней сетки

Tags: reactjs, рекурсия, react-grid-layout

У меня есть компонент CustomLayout, который рекурсивно выводит сам себя. Он имеет следующий вид:

```
import "./styles.css";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";
import React from "react";
import "react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
import "react-resizable/css/styles.css";

export default function CustomLayout({ layout, onDragStart, onDragStop }) {
  const [isDraggable, setIsDraggable] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <GridLayout
      className="layout"
      onDragStart={onDragStart}
      onDragStop={onDragStop}
      layout={layout}
      cols={12}
      rowHeight={80}
      width={1200}
      isDraggable={isDraggable}
    >
      {layout.map((item) => {
        if (item.children) {
          return (
            <div
              onClick={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent[0])}
              key={item.i}
              style={{ background: "pink", border: "1px solid black" }}
            >
              <CustomLayout
                layout={item.children}
                width={item.w * 10}
                onDragStart={() => {
                  setIsDraggable(false);
                }}
                onDragStop={() => {
                  setIsDraggable(true);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <div
              key={item.i}
              style={{ background: "purple" }}
              // onClick={(e) => console.log(item.i)}
            >
              {item.i}
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </GridLayout>
  );
}
```

layout - это массив, имеющий следующий вид:

```
  const layout = [
    { i: "b", x: 0, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2, isResizable: true },
    { i: "c", x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2, isResizable: true },
    {
      i: "k",
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      w: 6,
      h: 5,
      isResizable: true,
      children: [
        { i: "e", x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 2, isResizable: true },
        {
          i: "d",
          x: 2,
          y: 4,
          w: 3,
          h: 4,
          isResizable: true,
          children: [
            { i: "e", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1, isResizable: true },
            { i: "d", x: 1, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2, isResizable: true }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

То есть, на главной сетке выводятся корневые элементы массива, а если у элемента есть массив children, то рекурсивно создается дочерняя сетка.
Вопрос в следующем: главная сетка имеет ширину 1200 px (`width={1200}`). Я хочу сделать так, чтобы дочерние сетки имели ширину, которая высчитывается по формуле `width={item.w * 67}`, пробовал просто передавать это в дочернюю сетку, однако это не работает и ее ширина наследуется от родительской. Как можно реализовать эту логику? 
P.S. ссылка на CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-brahmagupta-727w42